# how to convert cakephp to windows desktop app

Tags: cakephp

I would like to convert my cakephp application to windows desktop application. I tried several solutions including the plugin cakephp "cakedesktop" and "exeoutput for php" which unfortunately do not work properly. I continue to seek without satisfactory results.
I am then back to you, thank you in advance for the solutions that you will propose to me.

Answer (score 2):

1. [PHP Nightrain](https://github.com/kjellberg/nightrain)
2. [Winbinder](http://winbinder.org/)
3. [wxPHP](https://wxphp.org/)
4. [TideSDK](http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/)
5. [PHPDesktop](https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop)

(First link work with cakephp, laravel, Drupal, Wordpress, ...).
Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you very much, I will test these links.